# How do i change this code of firebase V9?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm studying the React project through YouTube. But in the video, he wrote the code with firebase V8, but I'm trying to write the code with firebaseV9. What should I do?

I want to change the part below the db, but I don't know how

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './Orders.css'
import {useStateValue} from "./StateProvider";
import {collection, addDoc} from "./firebase";
import Order from "./Order";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

function Orders() {

    const [{ basket, user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user){
            await setDoc(doc(db,'user'),{

            });
            db
                .collection('users')
                .doc(user?.uid)
                .collection('orders')
                .orderBy('created', 'desc')
                .onSnapshot(snapshot => (
                    setOrders(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                        id:doc.id,
                        data:doc.data()
                    })))
                ))
        } else {
            setOrders([])
        }


    }, [user])


    return (
        <div className="orders">
            <h1> 주문내역 </h1>

            <div className='orders_order'>
                {orders?.map(order => (
                    <Order order={order} />
                ))}
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Orders;
```

I hope the part below the db is changed to the firestore code in the firebase V9 version format.

Comment: Were you able to run `setDoc()` successfully with V9 syntax? The `onSnapshot()` is a top level function in V9. Have you tried the example mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Comment: hmm i can understand documentation because i just start coding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is regarding this part?

```
db
                .collection('users')
                .doc(user?.uid)
                .collection('orders')
                .orderBy('created', 'desc')
                .onSnapshot(snapshot => (
                    setOrders(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                        id:doc.id,
                        data:doc.data()
                    })))
                ))
```

There is an `onSnapshot()` method, please check documentation for [orderBy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) and [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). Code should be something like this:

```js
if(user?.uid) {
const ordersRef = collection(db, "users", user.uid, orders);
const q = query(ordersRef, orderBy('created', 'desc'));
onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
// TODO: check if docs exist etc.
 setOrders(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                        id:doc.id,
                        data:doc.data()
                    })))
});
}

               
                .
```